# Deploying Graylog OVA on vSphere resutls in an error

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, deployment, vsphere

I am attempting to deploy a Graylog appliance on one of my VMs.

I have downloaded the latest stable version from [here](http://docs.graylog.org/en/latest/pages/installation/virtual_machine_appliances.html#virtual-machine-appliances) and attempted to deploy it via the VMWare ovftool. I executed the following command:

```
ovftool.exe --powerOn --datastore="datastore name" --network="network name" --lax "OVA location" vi://user@vm IP/DataCenter_Name/host/Host IP
```

However I received the following error:

```
Error: OVF Package is not supported by target:
 - Line 66: OVF hardware element 'ResourceType' with instance ID '5': No support for the virtual hardware device type '35'.
```

Some research finds that this type of problem might occur when exporting a VM from VirtualBox but that shouldn't be the case here.

Has any encountered anything similar to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the issue relates the ovf configuration. The following steps need to be taken:

1. Untar to ova file
2. Edit ovf file and remove reference to sound card item and save
3. Delete the mf file
4. Use the ovftool to deploy the ovf file